# Mixing version can lead to run time crashes

Tags: android-manifest, build.gradle, manifest, android-cardview, android-cards

There seems to be some problem in the Manifest file's second implementation line which is as (implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'). I am creating a map based app there was no error in the whole project. But this line is showing an error saying

"All com.android.supprt libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to run time run time crashes. Found version 26.1.0,25.2.0 .Examples include com.android.supprt:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0 and com.android.supprt:mediarouter-v7:25.2.0 more...(Ctrl + F1)"

When rebuilding app this error shows in the below bar

```
Error:Execution failed for task 
':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dexex"
```

This is my Manifest File Please Check it out. The error is in line number 15.

```
//noinspection GradleCompatible
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.matt.autoza"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

compile 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
compile 'com.github.glomadrian:MaterialAnimatedSwitch:1.1@aar'
compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
compile 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
compile 'com.github.glomadrian:MaterialAnimatedSwitch:1.1@aar'

compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'

compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
compile 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.0'


//removed
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.0' as there was no need for it
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1' 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'


//Updated the firebase versions accurately
compile 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'

//removed appCompat as that is no further required  in androidStudio
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'

compile 'com.github.glomadrian:MaterialAnimatedSwitch:1.1@aar'
compile 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'

compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'

try pasting these at the uppers place. This would solve the problem for sure
```